# custom DaoAuthenticationProvider doesnt check password

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am implementing spring Security in a Java EE application (Spring / Struts / Hibernate). I have some truble with my custum `DaoAuthenticationProvider`.

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder pAuth) throws Exception {
    pAuth.authenticationProvider(mAuthenticationProvider)
            .userDetailsService(mUserDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(new Md5PasswordEncoder());
}
```

This is in my `SecurityConfig` (extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`) class.
When I debug the app, I can see that in my custom `DaoAuthenticationProvider` the password encoder is not set (`PlainTextPasswordEncoder` instead of Md5), why ?

After that I tried to set manually in the constructor this values :

```
public LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider() {
    setPasswordEncoder(new Md5PasswordEncoder());
    setUserDetailsService(mUserDetailsService);
}
```

When I debug it I see the right values.

But in both cases, if I do :

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication pAuthentication) {
    Authentication lAuth = super.authenticate(pAuthentication);
    return lAuth;
}
```

The property of `lAuth` that indicate if user is authenticate or not is at true whatever the password is...
Does anyone have the answer ?

---

EDIT : `LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider` implementation

```
@Component("authenticationProvider")
public class LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {
    @Autowired
    private IUserDao mUserDao;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService mUserDetailsService;

    public LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider() {
        setPasswordEncoder(new Md5PasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    @Override
    public void setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        super.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication pAuthentication) {
        Authentication lAuth = super.authenticate(pAuthentication);
        return lAuth;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails pUserDetails,
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken pAuthentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            User lUser = mUserDao.findUserByLogin(pAuthentication.getName());
            if (lUser.getStatus() >= 3) {
                logger.debug("User account is locked");
                throw new LockedException(messages.getMessage(
                        "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.locked",
                        "User account is locked"));
            }
        } catch (DaoException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show you LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider implementation

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I missunderstood the objective of `DaoAuthenticationProvider`.
I think I have to check the password myself :

```
PasswordEncoder lPasswordEncoder = getPasswordEncoder();
if (!lPasswordEncoder.isPasswordValid(lUser.getPassword(),
        pAuthentication.getCredentials().toString(), null)) {
    throw new BadCredentialsException("Wrong password for user "
            + lUser.getLogin());
}
```

(am I wrong ?)

Comment: (but I still don't have my first answer...)